# Trigger se bloquea al ejecutar INSERT - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente trigger que he creado en mi tabla (base de datos MySql) pero al momento que voy a registrar un nuevo registro me devuelve el siguiente mensaje de error: 'can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement'.

Lo que deseo hacer con mi trigger es actualizar el monto de mi registro, es posible hacer eso con lo que tengo o que opciones puedo tomar dado que he leído que no es posible de utilizar este trigger en un insert. Gracias.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `request_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `request` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
Update request set cost = round((cost * 2) / 2, 1) where id = new.id;
END
```

Comment: Un trigger no puede actualizar la tabla que ha disparado su ejecución.

Comment: Es decir: ¿Una vez que haces el `INSERT` quieres incrementar el valor que una de esos valores tiene, del nuevo registro?

Comment: Lo que deseo hacer es actualizar el registro insertado

Comment: Entonces debes actualizar el valor de `NEW.cost` y no hacer un `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que no puedes modificar la tabla que ha generado la ejecución de un disparador. Sólo puedes modificar los valores que se guardarán finalmente en el registro accediendo a las variables `NEW.*`.

Puedes modificar el valor que será guardado (`NEW.cost`) de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER request_BEFORE_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON request
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.cost = round((NEW.cost * 2) / 2, 1);
END
```

Puedes ver esto en el apartado de [preguntas frecuentes de la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-triggers-tables):

> A.5.9. *Can triggers access tables?*
>
> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger can also affect other tables, **but it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger**.

En castellano:

> A.5.9. *¿Un disparador puede acceder a las tablas?*
>
> Un disparador puede acceder a los datos viejos y nuevos de su propia tabla. Incluso puede modificar otras tablas, **pero no tiene permitido modificar la tabla que ya está en uso (para lectura o escritura) por la consulta que invocó la función o disparador**.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió.